# php for loop to get every URL address

Tags: php

I'm stuck with making a PHP for loop to get every URL address.  I really appreciate your help in advance.

URL goes like this incremented by 1 :

```
http://www.4hb.com/letters/index.html
http://www.4hb.com/letters/index1.html
http://www.4hb.com/letters/index2.html
http://www.4hb.com/letters/index3.html
```

And here is my code:

```
for ($i=1;$i<3;$i++) {
    $url="http://www.4hb.com/letters/index".$i.".html";
    include 'class.snoopy.php';
    $s=new snoopy;
    $s->fetch($url);
    $txt=$s->results;
}
```

Comment: How did you save the URLs? Is it an array or does it fetched from database? Textfile? Or just some random urls?

Comment: Exactly what problem are you experiencing?  Is an error produced?  Are you just not sure how to accomplish something?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot `}`? Also `include` can be taken out of the loop.

```
include 'class.snoopy.php';
$urls = [];

for ($i=1; $i<3; $i++) {
    $url="http://www.4hb.com/letters/index".$i.".html";
    $s = new snoopy();
    $s->fetch($url);
    $urls[] = $s->results;
}

print_r($urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code you can only have $i=1, for the first loop and $i=2 for the second one, then the loop stops. So you get:

```
http://www.4hb.com/letters/index1.html
http://www.4hb.com/letters/index2.html
```

Change you loop like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    if ($i==0){
        $url="http://www.4hb.com/letters/index.html";
    }
    else {
        $url="http://www.4hb.com/letters/index".$i.".html";
    }
    include 'class.snoopy.php';
    $s=new snoopy;
    $s->fetch($url);
    $txt=$s->results;
}
```

I'm not sure where your problem was, but this solves the loop problem :)